# Trouble Parsing Array vs Non-Array JSON with JSONPath

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have JSON that looks like the below.  I'm trying to use [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) to grab the __ content __ value where the SKU is "8A-OK9F-9LI8" AND the Component.Type == 'Principal'.  Right now, I am playing around with [this](https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/) JSON Path Expression Tester.

This JSONPath expression grabs all of the component information I need:

```
$.Order..Fulfillment[?(@.SKU=='8A-OK9F-9LI8')]..Component
```

But filtering further such as `$.Order..Fulfillment[?(@.SKU=='8A-OK9F-9LI8')]..Component[?(@.Type=='Principal')]` grabs only one (I believe the Array one) of the two Component elements I need.  I suspect this is because one is an Array and one is a single JSON element.  Is it possible to grab this with one command or do I have to combine several commands (one for the Array and one for the single JSON element)?  If so, how can I grab the other Component information that I am not currently getting with:

`$.Order..Fulfillment[?(@.SKU=='8A-OK9F-9LI8')]..Component[?(@.Type=='Principal')]`?

Again, my goal is to grab the "__ content__" value and filter by a specific SKU and where the Component.Type == 'Principal'.  Something like:

`$.Order..Fulfillment[?(@.SKU=='8A-OK9F-9LI8')]..Component[?(@.Type=='Principal')]..Amount..__content__`

I'm expecting to get back `["8.49", "8.49"]`

Here is the JSON I am testing with:

```
{
  "SettlementData": {},
  "Order": [
    {
      "OrderID": "XXX",
       "Fulfillment": {
        "Item": {
          "SKU": "8A-OK9F-9LI8",
          "Quantity": "1",
          "ItemPrice": {
            "Component": [
              {
                "Type": "Principal",
                "Amount": {
                  "__content__": "8.49",
                  "currency": "USD"
                }
              },
              {
                "Type": "Tax",
                "Amount": {
                  "__content__": "0.74",
                  "currency": "USD"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "OrderID": "XXX",
      "Fulfillment": {
        "Item": {
          "SKU": "8A-OK9F-9LI8",
          "Quantity": "1",
          "ItemPrice": {
            "Component": {
              "Type": "Principal",
              "Amount": {
                "__content__": "8.49",
                "currency": "USD"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this in two passes.  In this example, `#{sku}` is a Ruby interpolated string that contains the SKU I am passing in:

```
$.Order..Fulfillment[?(@.SKU=='#{sku}')]..ItemPrice..[?(@.Type=='Principal')].Amount.__content__

$.Order..Fulfillment..Item[?(@.SKU=='#{sku}')]..ItemPrice..[?(@.Type=='Principal')].Amount.__content__
```

Using a Ruby gem "[jsonpath](https://github.com/joshbuddy/jsonpath)", I was able to get the amounts I needed like this:

```
  amount     = JsonPath.on(settlement, "$.Order..Fulfillment[?(@.SKU=='#{sku}')]..ItemPrice..[?(@.Type=='Principal')].Amount.__content__")
    .map(&:to_f).inject(:+)
  amount2    = JsonPath.on(settlement, "$.Order..Fulfillment..Item[?(@.SKU=='#{sku}')]..ItemPrice..[?(@.Type=='Principal')].Amount.__content__")
    .map(&:to_f).inject(:+)
```

Comment: This seems to be a limitation in the library I'm using.  I have since converted every hash element to be an Array to overcome this.  Thanks for down voting without providing a reason why.